# Execute a command in the future in dart

Tags: dart

I have build a server application and need to schedule some commands in the future. Somethink like this:

```
On 28 oktober 2018 at 13.00 print('Hello, World!');
```

Whats the best possibility to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To schedule an event at some time in the future, you can use either [`Timer`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.0.0/dart-async/Timer/Timer.html) or `Future.delayed`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.0.0/dart-async/Future/Future.delayed.html).
They both take a [`Duration`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.0.0/dart-core/Duration-class.html) as argument, which is an amount of time to wait, rather than a specific time to trigger at. (It's not a coincidence that the two ways are similar, the future constructor uses a timer internally).

For something like this, I would use a timer. 
Example:

```
DateTime whenToRun = DateTime(2018, 10, 28, 13, 0);
// Calculate the length of the duration from now to when we should run.
Duration durationUntil = whenToRun.difference(DateTime.now());
// (Maybe add a check that the duration isn't negative, in case we are
// already past the point in time).
Timer timer = Timer(durationUntil, () {
  print("Hello, World!");  // or whatever you want.
});
```

This will schedule a timer which will trigger at October 28th, 2018, at 13:00.

If you change your mind and want to cancel the timer before that, you can use `timer.cancel()`.

This ovciously assumes that your program keeps running until the time is up.

Comment: I will try. Thank you.